# eslint warning vs proptypes warning

Tags: javascript, react-native, eslint, react-proptypes

I have a component as below with an attribute to accept a boolean value

```
let this.props.error = null; //For illustration purpose

<AlertModal
  isVisible={this.props.error}
/>
```

`this.props.error` will be an object with initial value as null, which is one of the falsey value. The above code will throw me a warning

> Warning: Failed prop type: The prop `isVisible` is marked as required but it's value is null

I then change it to below version

```
<AlertModal
  isVisible={this.props.error ? true : false}
/>
```

The previous warning gone but new warning from eslint saying

> unnecessarily use of boolean literals in conditional expression

Why in the first case null is not being considered a falsey value? For this use case, other than writing separately to handle the value, what's the best recommended way to handle it?

Comment: Wild guess, I don't know about `isVisible`, but try `isVisible={ Boolean(this.props.error) }` maybe?

Comment: Also, I would try `isVisible={this.props.error || false}` or `isVisible={!!this.props.error}`

Comment: Yeah explicit coercion is working fine. Guess I've relied too much on implicit coercion